# How can I show InfluxDb tags only for todays date?

Tags: tags, grafana, influxdb

I am having trouble getting this query in InfluxDb to work properly.  Wondering if someone can help.

I want to show tag values but only for the current days data.  I have this

```
SHOW TAG VALUES FROM table WITH KEY = "name"
```

This list shows all values from the full measurement.  I want to only show values for data that was inserted today.

I've tried

```
  SHOW TAG VALUES FROM table WITH KEY = "name" where date='2018-10-23'
  SHOW TAG VALUES FROM table WITH KEY = "name" where time='2018-10-23'
```

as well as some other variations but can't seem to get this right.
Does anyone know how to properly form this query?

I am using this as a variable inside Grafana.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

how about use subquery? instead of "show tag values"
like this

```
# show tag values from with key = “TAGName” where condition
select TagName from (select field, TagName from Measurement where condition)
```

it return timestamp with tag values

Comment: This one works. You can get a time series with all entries of TagName.

Answer (score 1):

For select time you mast define time range, start and end. 
This is working solution.

```
SHOW TAG VALUES FROM table WITH KEY = "name" where time>='2020-04-26T00:00:00Z' AND time<'2020-04-27T00:00:00Z'
```

Answer (score 0):

Time condition is not supported in `SHOW TAG VALUES` query - there is an issue for that https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/5668. You can find a workaround with a continuous query in that issue comments.

Answer (score 0):

Can't upvote answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58404465/18224224 but this solution has worked for me.

```
select "tag_name" from (select "field_value", "tag_name" from "table" WHERE "tag_name_filter" = 'tag_value_filter' AND  $timeFilter group by "tag_name" LIMIT 1)
```

`$timefilter` variable will automatically use dashboard time range selected if variable uses **refresh : on time range change**

[Grafana Dashboard variables screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFyWV.png)

[Grafana Dashboard variables screenshot with different time range selected in dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUbWV.png)